# How to find the time of any point on the graph on an Arduino serial plotter or Processing software?

Tags: arduino-ide, sensors, arduino-pro-mini, processing-lang

I am plotting the graph of some sensor values on my Arduino serial plotter which looks something like this -[image]

But what I want to do is hover over any point on the graph and display the time at that point. Is there any way to do that, if not with Arduino serial plotter, with Processing? Or any other tool is fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Serial Plotter is not meant for this. It just directly draws, what you send. You can solve this in processing, by calculating the time from the number of the current sample (which is what you see on the x axis in your plot) via the used sampling rate.

Comment: Can I use the system time for this? I just want to find the difference between the time period of each crest or trough of the blue and red waveforms respectively. I have done it using my code but I want to verify it graphically.

Comment: What do you mean by "the system"? You want to plot the data on your PC. Processing is a tool, that is made for such situations. The difference between the plot above and what you want is just a simple factor multiplied to the x axis value: the sampling rate

Comment: why do you need system time? ... you said that you want to determine a time interval between two points

Comment: >`I just want to find the difference between the time period of each crest` Arduino can do that for you as well

Comment: @DataFiddler >`I have done it using my code but I want to verify it graphically.`. I think his goal is to have a graphical useable plotter.